# Racket switch statement macro

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm trying to make a switch statement macro in Racket. I'm having some trouble figuring out excatly how to do it. I would like to be able to use the function as shown below.

```
(define x 99)

(switch x
    [3 (displayln "x is 3")]
    [4 (displayln "x is 4")]
    [5 (displayln "x is 5")]
    ['default (displayln "none of the above")])
```

I've tried using pattern matching with syntax-case but i'm not sure that is the correct approach. Any Racket experts here that could give me a push in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

I believe in not reinventing perfectly good wheels, so here's a macro for transforming your `switch` into the equivalent `case`, with a slight change to use `default` instead of `'default`. (I apologise to soegaard, for not knowing how to use `syntax-parse` yet, so I'll just stick with traditional `syntax-case` instead. ;-))

```
(define-syntax (switch stx)
  (define (transform-clause cl)
    (syntax-case cl (default)
      ((default expr) #'(else expr))
      ((val ... expr) #'((val ...) expr))))

  (define (transform-clauses cls)
    (syntax-case cls ()
      ((cl)
       (with-syntax ((case-clause (transform-clause #'cl)))
         #'(case-clause)))
      ((cl rest ...)
       (with-syntax ((case-clause (transform-clause #'cl))
                     ((case-rest ...) (transform-clauses #'(rest ...))))
         #'(case-clause case-rest ...)))))

  (syntax-case stx ()
    ((_ x clause ...)
     (with-syntax (((case-clause ...) (transform-clauses #'(clause ...))))
       #'(case x case-clause ...)))))
```

The downside of using this `switch` macro, as opposed to using `case`, is that you lose the ability to distinguish between using `default` to match the symbol `default`, vs as the catch-all. So using `case` is still better. :-)

```
(case x
  ((3) (displayln "x is 3"))
  ((4) (displayln "x is 4"))
  ((5) (displayln "x is 5"))
  (else (displayln "none of the above")))
```

Comment: `(syntax-case (default) stx clause)` and `(syntax-parse stx #:literals(default) clause ...)` mean the same (assuming you are not using any guards. It's just that easy!

Answer (score 2):

I like both of the other answers, but I feel like we should also mention the existing `match` form, which (afaict) already does exactly what you're looking for:

```
#lang racket

(define x 99)

(match x
  [3 (displayln "x is 3")]
  [4 (displayln "x is 4")]
  [5 (displayln "x is 5")]
  [default (displayln "none of the above")])
```

The only changes: I write `match` instead of `switch`, and I use the pattern `default` rather than the quoted `'default`. In fact, any identifier would work here; an identifier just gives a name to a value.

Indeed, match can do a whole lot more than this, but this is one great use for it.

If you're just looking for practice in writing macros, then you can disregard this answer :).

Answer (score 1):

For `switch` I recommend making a helper macro that switches on a value - this avoids the problem of evaluating the `expr` in `(switch expr clause ...)` more than once.

Below I used the identifier `else` to indicate the default clause.

Note that `syntax-parse` try the patterns one-at-a-time. This is used to catch raise syntax errors given faulty input such as `(switch)`

The initial identifier in the patterns are prefixed with a `_` to avoid any problems in recursive macros.

Note that the basic rewrite rule used is:

```
(switch-value v
   [expr result]
   clause ...)

==>

(if (equal? v expr)
    result
    (switch-value v clause ...))
```

Making the macro recursive is easier than writing one big macro that handles all clauses at once.

```
#lang racket

(require (for-syntax syntax/parse))

(define-syntax (switch stx)
  (syntax-parse stx
    [(_switch)
     #'(raise-syntax-error 'switch "value expression and at least one clause expected" stx)]
    [(_switch expr clause ...)
     #'(let ([v expr])
         (switch-value v clause ...))]))

(define-syntax (switch-value stx)
  (syntax-parse stx
    #:literals (else)
    [(_switch-value v)
     #'(raise-syntax-error 'switch "at least one clause is expected" _switch-value)]
    [(_switch-value v [else expr])
     #'expr]
    [(_switch-value v [expr1 expr2] clause ...)
     #'(if (equal? v expr1)
           expr2
           (switch-value v clause ...))]))


(define x 4)

(switch x
  [3 "x is 3"]
  [4 "x is 4"]
  [5 "x is 5"]
  [else (displayln "none of the above")])
```